# How to Convert a String Variable to a Boolean Variable in Java?

Tags: java, string, boolean

I am very, very new at programming so sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can't find an answer anywhere.

In a program that I am working on the user can choose one of five options for problems to practice: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and remainders. There is a scanner that asks them to put in the fist letter of the name of the types of problems they want to practice (A or a, S or s, M or m, D or d, R or r). I want to make an if/else statement that will print out different problems depending on which one they choose.

The problem is, from what I can tell if/else statements will only work with boolean variables,  but boolean variables don't like strings or string variables. I have seen ways to convert specific strings to variables, but since the user is deciding on the string, I have no way to know what they are going to choose every time. Is there anyway to convert a string variable to a boolean variable?? (i.e. the boolean variable is true when the string variable = "A")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if`(s) can take `boolean` expressions (and use *`boolean` operators*, such as `or`). For example, [`String.equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) (or [`String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-)). Something like,

```
if (string.equals("A") || string.equals("a")) {
    // ...
} else if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {// <-- or equalsIgnoreCase(String).
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, my favorite way is to use a `switch` statement when you're dealing with input, and while it doesn't use boolean values as you are use to in an `if` statement, for me it feels cleaner.

Your code would look like something such as:

```
switch(userInput.toLowerCase())
{
    case "a":
    // addition code
    break;
    case "s":
    // subtraction code
    break;
    case "m":
    // multiplication code
    break;
    case "d":
    // division code
    break;
    case "r":
    // remainder code
    break;
    default: // every other option besides (a, s, m, d, and r)
    // print some error, user put wrong input
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ypu can use

```
java.lang.Boolean(String s)
```

> Allocates a Boolean object representing the value true if the string
>   argument is not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string
>   "true".

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do.You're dealing with a fairly simple problem.

**Pseudo-Code**

```
if(input=="A")
{
Do Addition
}
if(input=="M")
{
Do Multiplication
}
else
{
Give Error
}
```

Essentially, you want to check if the user input is equal to a particular string. You use the double equal to operator (`==`) here to perform the check.If  the condition is *TRUE* and it will enter the block.

Answer (score 0):

The Point is that the if block is evaluated on the basis of any expression that results into boolean values(i.e. true or false).

So there is no need to convert a String to Boolean.

All you have to do is just check if input string meets your criteria using a method provided by String Class in java called String.equals(String) or String.equalsIgnoreCase(String);

The return type of above methods is boolean (primitive) which will be evaluated by if statement as per your requirements.

*To explore String Class in java
run "javap java.lang.String" on shell/bash/command prompt for programmer's guide to check out the contents of String Class*

So your code will be something like

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
{
  // Calculations for addition
}
else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) 
{
  // Calculations for Substraction
}
```

Instead you can use switch-case as support for String in switch-case has been included from jdk7.

Also switch-case should be faster in this case as it will not check all cases as done by else if.

```
switch(input)
{
    case "a":
    case "A":
        // Calculations for addition
        break;
    case "s":
    case "S"
        // Calculations for subtraction
        break;
    case "m":
    case "M":
        // Calculations for multiplication
        break;
    case "d":
    case "D":
        // Calculations for division
        break;
    case "r":
    case "R":
        // Calculations for remainder
        break;
    default: // for any other option besides above
        // whatever handling you wanna do for wrong input
        break;
}
```